# Mysql Select table IF

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I was hoping someone could help me, I have 3 tables (Amy,Ben,Carl) I also have another table, Staff. How would I go about writing a statement that would select Amy, Ben or Carl dependent on a value in staff?

I'm able to grab info out of the Staff table using this query:

```
<?php
  include"session.php";//database connection
  $order = "SELECT * FROM staff WHERE Email='$login_session'";
  $result = mysql_query($order);
  while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo ("<tr><td>$row[Password]</td>");
    echo ("<td>$row[Address]</td>");
    echo ("<td>$row[PhoneNumber]</td>");
    echo ("<td>$row[Email]</td>");
    echo ("<td><a href=\"edit_form.php?id=$row[Forename]\">Edit</a></td></tr>");
  }
  ?>
```

How would I change this code that it will only select table Amy if $login_session is = to her email address in the staff table?

```
<?php
  include"session.php";//database connection
  $order = "SELECT * FROM amy";
  $result = mysql_query($order);
  while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo ("<tr><td>$row[Date]</td>");
    echo ("<td>$row[Mon]</td>");
    echo ("<td>$row[Tue]</td>");
    echo ("<td>$row[Wed]</td>");
    echo ("<td>$row[Thu]</td>");
    echo ("<td>$row[Fri]</td>");
    echo ("<td>$row[Sat]</td>");
    echo ("<td>$row[Sun]</td>");
    echo ("<td><a href=\"edit_form.php?id=$row[Forename]\">Edit</a></td></tr>");
  }
  ?>
```

Thanks

Comment: is there any specific reason you have 3 completely separate tables, instead of maybe a column which signifies which group (or equivalent to this) they belong to?

Comment: What do those tables (apart from staff) look like?

Comment: This is a problem of poor design!

Comment: Read up on joins: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/ - If there's nothing in common with any table, then use `UNION`.

Comment: The Amy,ben and carl tables are simply calendars personal to them which they will eventually be able to use to book holiday and days they wish to work. My tutor told me that the best way to do it is with a table each. When they login with their details from staff they need to be presented with their personal calendar

Comment: Look at the logic behind your tutor's idea; 10,000 users and 10,000 calendars, *ouch*. Why a table for each user, when you can just use a `WHERE` clause and feed them the related data.

Comment: All of the PHP mysql_* functions are deprecated, you should switch to mysqli_* versions of the functions (php.net/mysql_query).

Comment: ... and use bind_param as well; don't just switch the API and leave the simple string insertion in there. Never put $_POST params directly into a sql query string!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The calendars should be one table with a user id field, so you can use a SQL WHERE:

e.g. 
    SELECT event_id, event_datetime, event_duration, event_description FROM calendar WHERE
    user_id='[add your single-quote escaped user id here]';